# Colored iCal style checkboxes using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to get colored checkboxes like in iCal without using custom drawing?

I have looked through the documentation but can only find how to change the background and text color.

Comment: Minor suggestion: Think of those with color blindness. If the color has significant meaning (not just "pretty"), make sure color isn't the only thing that indicates this meaning. iCal lets you choose a color for a calendar, but a calendar also has a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit dated (runs back on 10.3), but Matt Gemmell published a some code for doing colored checkboxes a few years back.

http://mattgemmell.com/source

Look for "iTableView."

I looked at the code when it was first available, but not since. There might be a better way to do it at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something at least similar to the colored checkboxes in iCal by enabling Core Animation for the checkbox and adding a "Hue Adjust" (in "Color Adjustment") content filter.  If the color is static, this can be done entirely within Interface Builder, no code needed.

Be careful, though, as sometimes enabling Core Animation for various views causes strange bugs (for example, WebViews don't play nice with Core Animation views).

If you want to do it programmatically, take a look at the documentation for [`CIFilter`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (that's a link), which you use with the NSView instance method [`setContentFilters:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW71) (also a link).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. I'm not sure if the AHIG forbids this sort of thing or not, (it probably does), but the reason iCal gets away with it is because, 'Hey! Why not?'. Also, it's an Apple application, so yeah.

It can still be done, of course, but not without custom drawing. Personally, I'd advise against it, and rather see if what you are trying to achieve could be achieved some other way. If not, you could possibly use some of the data files from iCal to build your checkbox. (Unsure of how kosher *that* would be, but 'Hey! Why not?'.)